# display form data in another view in Zend

Tags: zend-framework, view, controller, zend-form

I am new in Zend, my problem can be simple for you. I want to make a controller that displays form input data in another view. data are an email text and a text file uploaded. I created the index view and result view.
but i get nothing. when I replace the value of $email with text it works!! I can't find what is going wrong.
The controller also should display a sorted file by firstname

```
Id,Firstname,Lastname
5,John,Doe
6,Adam,Ant
7,Victor,Hugo
8,Britannie,Spears
```

this is my controller :

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        // initialzing of the customized form
        $form = new Application_Form_Upload();

        $rq = $this->getRequest();

        $isForm = true; // the form has to be shown only if true

        if ($rq->isPost()) {
            if ($form->isValid($rq->getPost())) {
                // show the uploaded data instead of the form
                $isForm = false;
                $this->view->data = new Application_Model_DataViewer();
                $this->view->data->parseFromForm($form);

                $result = new Zend_View();
                $this->view->result= $result;
                $this->render('result');
            }
        }

        if ($isForm) {
            $this->view->form = $form;}
    }
```

this is my model :

```
class Application_Model_DataViewer
{
    /**
     * @var string Entered e-mail address
     */
    private $email;
    /**
     * @var array Array of extracted data from uploaded file
     */
    private $data;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->email=null;
        $this->data=array();
    }

    /**
     * Extracts the data from the form-object and saves it internally
     * @param $form Application_Form_Upload
     */
    public function parseFromForm($form){
        if(!isset($form))return;
        if(!isset($form->file)||!$form->file instanceof Zend_Form_Element_File){
            throw new Zend_Exception('The field File is empty or has wrong type');
        }

        // for validation of the IDs
        $ival = new Zend_Validate_Int();

        // reading the CSV-file (values should be separated by comma, if not - should be extended)
        if(($fp = @fopen($form->file->getFileName(), 'r')) !== false){
            while(($data = fgetcsv($fp, 500, ',')) !== false){
                if(
                    !is_array($data)
                    ||!$ival->isValid($data[0])
                    ||count($data)<3
                )continue;
                $this->data[$data[1]] = $data;
            }
        }else{return;}
        @fclose($fp);

        ksort($this->data);

        $this->email = $form->getValue('email');
    }

    /**
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function getEmail(){
        return $this->email;

    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData(){
        return $this->data;
    }

}
```

and here is my index and result views

```
<?php 
// the form should only be rendered if form must be shown
if(isset($this->form)){
    $this->form->setAction($this->url());
    echo $this->form; 
}
?>
```

result view:

```
<?php 
// if the required data is submitted, it will be checked and displayed
if(isset($this->data)){
?>
<p>Thank you <strong><?php echo $this->escape($this->data->getEmail()); ?></strong>.</p>

<p>The result of the sorting is:
<?php
    foreach($this->data->getData() as $row){
        echo '<div>', $this->escape($row[0]), ',',
            $this->escape($row[1]), ',',
            $this->escape($row[2]), '</div>';
    }
?></p><?php
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the partial helper in the view.

See: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.partial.html

eg. your index.phtml

```
if ($this->data) {
    echo $this->partial("result.phtml", array("data" => $this->data->getData()));
}
```

you can access the variable in result.phtml by **$this->data**

Comment: but I still get a wrong display. the function parseFromForm($form) seems not reading the file. when I modifier my view to this : foreach($this->data as $row){
  echo    $this->escape($row[0]), ',',
   $this->escape($row[1]), ',',
   $this->escape($row[2]), '<br />';  I get this : The result of the sorting is: 1,2,3